# tmp directory in wso2 application server

Tags: wso2, wso2-wsas

I have a `wso2 wsas3.1.1` in my production environment. It has about 8.6 GB of data in `$CARBON_HOME/tmp‌`
 folder. I browsed it's files and I have no idea about what are they and what they do. I want to remove all files and folders in the `tmp` folder, does it make any differences? Is it harmful?
Also I want to know that why the Housekeeping task does not clear the `tmp` folder based on time schedules?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is fine to remove the `tmp` directory.  It would not harmful. There is some housekeeping task to clean this directory. But it seems to be that it is not working according to the [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-11926). Therefore i think, It is better to write some task to do it.

Comment: So you say that I can clean the directory completely? Is there a way that I can get sure about harmless remove?

Comment: Yes. Please check source here. WSO2 code has task to clean it. (however it is not working). Therefore I think,  It must be safe to delete it as WSO2 has implementation to do it. http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/core/org.wso2.carbon.core/4.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/core/util/HouseKeepingTask.java

Comment: Very great! Not only you answered me but also you taught me that I can dig into the real source of open source projects to handle my problems. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can delete content of tmp directory. Just don't delete tmp directory entirely, because when you start the product it will delete all loaded files which are all configuration files, bin etc. Tmp directory has to exists on product start. Tested with WSO2 Integrator 6.1.1